# Inovoking R Script from remote machine with SSH is failing

Tags: ssh, rscript

I am using R for doing some process and I am trying to automate this job. R script resides in some other machine. I need to invoke this script form some other machine and I am invoking the script using ssh .. user@myip "Rscript MyRCode.R". It is invoking the script on remote machine and I could see logs also.

In my R Code I have these statement library(devtools) library(qdap) library(RJDBC) etc..

When I connect to the remote machine and if I run this R script it is executing, but when I try to execute it with ssh it is not able to find deltools package.

For this I tried to add library(devtools, lib.loc="/folder1/folder2/libpath")
and followed the same for other packages as well. (also tried with adding same path in .libPaths(...))

This time devtools loaded, but for qdap it is saying "object is masked from 'package.base'" and then it is failing

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Adding ".libPaths(proper_lib_path)" with proper location in the beginning of the script is worked for me.

But still I am getting object is masked from 'package.base', but this can be ignored.